# Using DHT to lookup stuff. SHA-1. Chord protocol

Tags: java, distributed-computing, distributed-caching, dht, chord

I'm trying to implement the Chord protocol in order to quickly lookup some nodes and keys in a small network. What I can't figure out is ... Chord cosideres the nodes and keys as being placed on a cirlce. And their placement dictated by the hash values obtained by applying the SHA-1 hash function. How exactly do I operate with those values? Do I make them as a string `de9f2c7f d25e1b3a fad3e85a 0bd17d9b 100db4b3` and then compare them as such, considering that `"a" < "b" is true` ? Or how? How do I know if a key is before or after another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keyspace is a ring, a single value can't be said to be greater than another, because if you go the other way around the ring, the opposite is true.  You *can* say a value is within a range or not.  In the Chord DHT, each server is responsible for the keys within the range of values between it and its predecessor.

I would advise against using strings for the hash values.  You [shouldn't use the `hashCode` function for distributed systems](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/06/18/java-hashcode-unsafe-for-distributed-systems.html), but you need to math on the hash keys when adding new nodes.  You could try converting the hashes into [BigIntegers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

sha1 hashes are not strings but are very long hex numbers - they are often stored as strings because they would otherwise require a native 160 bit number type. They are built as 5 32 bit hex numbers and then often 'strung' together.

using sha1 strings as the numbers they represent is not hard but requires a library that can handle such large numbers (like BigInt or bcmath). these libraries work by calculating the numbers within the string one column at a time from the right to left, much like a person when using a pen and paper to add, multiply, divide, etc. they will typically have functions for doing common math as well comparisons etc, and often take strings as arguments. Also, make sure that you use a function for converting big numbers anytime you need to go from hex to dec, or else your 160 bit hex number will likely get rounded into a 64 bit dec float or similar and loose most of it's accuracy.

more/less than comparisons *are* used in chord to figure ranges but do so using modulo so that they 'wrap', making ranges such as [64, 2] possible. the actual formula is

```
find_successor(fingers[k] = n + 2^(k-1) mod(2^160))
```

where 'n' is the sha1 of a node and 'k' is the finger number.

remember, 'n' will be hex while 'k' and 'mod(160^2)' will typically be dec, so this is where your BigInt hex to BigInt dec will be needed.

even if your programing framework will let you create these vars as hex, 160 is specifically a dec (literally meaning one hounded and sixty bits) and besides, wrapping your brain around 'mod(160^2)' is already hard enough without visualizing it as hex. convert 'n' to dec rather than converting 'k' etc to hex , and then use a BigInt lib to do the math including comparisons.